# image links and hover doesn't work in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a navigation menu with images. The *links* don't work in IE9 even though there's no problem with Chrome and Firefox. The hover effect doesn't work also.

Check out what I've got at [www.sabourinpaulwedding.ca](http://www.sabourinpaulwedding.ca)

Thanks in advance.
Gilles

The HTML is a vertical navigational bar on the left and a content div on the right.

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="welcome"><a class="selected" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="ceremony"><a href="ceremony.html"></a></li>
    <li class="reception"><a href="reception.html"></a></li>
    <li class="accommodations"><a href="accommodations.html"></a></li>
    <li class="registry"><a href="registry.html"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Welcome to the digital home of the future Mr. and Mrs. Paul.</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

The CSS uses images to display the hovered link and the selected link.
It seems the IE can't access the navigation bar because an "invisible" div is on top.
I played with the z-index for the nav bar. That didn't work.

```
ul.nav
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    z-index: 20;
}

ul.nav a
{
    border: 0px solid #cccccc;
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    padding-top: 72px;
    width: 265px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Welcome Button */
.nav li.welcome a { background:url('images/welcome_en_normal.png') no-repeat; background-position:0px 0px; }
.nav li.welcome a:hover { background:url('images/welcome_en_hover.png') no-repeat; background-position:0px 0px; }
.nav li.welcome a.selected { background:url('images/welcome_en_selected.png') no-repeat; background-position:0px 0px; }

/* Ceremony Button */
.nav li.ceremony a { background:url('images/ceremony_en_normal.png') no-repeat; background-position:0px 0px; }
.nav li.ceremony a:hover { background:url('images/ceremony_en_hover.png') no-repeat; background-position:0px 0px; }
.nav li.ceremony a.selected { background:url('images/ceremony_en_selected.png') no-repeat; background-position:0px 0px; }
```

What does work though is removing all p tags from the content side... but I do need some content (obviously). The problem is not in the css .p selector because if I remove everything in there, the links still won't work.

Comment: Please show some effort by at least putting your (appropriate) code into your post... And what have you tried si far?

Comment: Obligatory [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Could be because of a z-index issue, i.e. another element overlaying the A tags that swallows the click events. Code or link is needed.

Comment: I am curious to see why you feel the need to use images for a menu...I strongly believe in using regular text and css only (without images that replaces text). Your site becomes useless to the blind (which is a growing democratic)

Comment: Well... I'm not a pro. I wish I could do it all in text but it took me quite a while to get where I am.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the tags are empty try this markup

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="welcome"><a href="#" class="selected">Welcome</a></li>
    <li class="ceremony"><a href="ceremony.html">Ceremony</a></li>
    <li class="reception"><a href="reception.html">Reception</a></li>
    <li class="accommodations"><a href="accommodations.html">Accomodations</a></li>
    <li class="registry"><a href="registry.html">Registry</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And CSS

```
ul.nav a {
    border: 0 solid #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    height:0;
    padding-top: 72px;
    width: 265px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Has the side-effect of being SEO friendly as bonus

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that code but it doesn't do it. Is there a way to force the navigational bar to be on "top" of the the right content? 
It's as if the mouse can't access the nav menu in IE. If I remove the p tags in the content, the links will work.

Comment: Can you jsfiddle something for us please?

Comment: I've never heard of jsfiddle until now. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Here. I've removed all the non essential code... just a few lines. Here's the jsfiddle link [http://jsfiddle.net/jude316/87RvT/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/jude316/87RvT/7/)